# How to convert incoming hex values from serial port in C?

Tags: c, visual-studio, type-conversion, serial-port, hex

**Overview:** I want to use Visual Studio (in C) to read a little-endian HEX value of a 24-byte data packet from a sensor over a serial COM port. I need to update the serial read whenever new data is sent to the port and interpret some bytes of the data as float values. How could I go about reading from the COM port when serial data is available, organizing the bytes, and converting them to floats/useful information?

**Details:** The incoming packets are a known 24 byte length and start/end with known characters ("{" and "}"), so that helps with knowing how many bytes to catch and how to break them down. Bytes 7-10 contain the gas 1 concentration data in little-endian Hex format, bytes 11-14 contain the gas 2 concentration data in little-endian Hex format. An example packet is shown below:

[Example 24-byte HEX packet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGunZ.png)

Another example of a similar packet (provided by the sensor's datasheet) is shown below:

[Example 24-byte HEX packet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC5KN.png)

The pseudocode I've mapped out for the whole operation is outlined like this:

```
If serial data is available{

    //read serial packet into char array
    Char serialString[24]  = read serial until newline character () 

    startBracketHexChar = serialString[0] //”{“ part of packet
    Gas1HexChar= serialString[6-9]      //gas measurement 1 data from packet
    Gas2HexChar = serialString[10-13]   //gas measurement 2 data from packet
    tempHexChar = serialString[14-17]   //temp measurement from packet
    endBracketHexChar = serialString[23]        //”}” part of bracket

    //if packet is as expected…
    if (startBracketHexChar == ‘{‘ && endBrackHexChar == ‘}’){  

        Gas1Float = char.to.float(Gas1HexChar)  //convert char to float type
        Gas2Float = char.to.float(Gas2HexChar)  //convert char to float type
        tempFloat = char.to.float(tempHexChar)  //convert char to float type
        gas1textBox.Text = Gas1Float;           //display gas 1 reading 
        gas2textBox.Text = Gas2Float;           //display gas 2 reading 
        temptextBox.Text = tempFloat;           //display temp reading
    }
    else {
        ErrortextBox.Text = “Packet error”; //unexpected packet error
    }
}
```

I think I'm very incorrect about my assumptions in the pseudocode about reading the Gas1HexChar array (maybe it needs to be read character by character and stitched together instead of in one array chunk?) and converting it (hiccups in calling a char string a Hex value and then converting that hex value to float?) - this is where my knowledge and experience are very limited and implementation suggestions would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Just so that we are in agreement: the data is binary - it is just the sample dumps that show it as hexadecimal, for clarity. So to parse a float field, for instance, you need to process its 4 bytes as one variable.

Comment: Good point - the data is binary. So when the sensor outputs "0x42477105" byte-wise in the 8-bit little-endian form of "05 71 47 42" I would receive the binary bytes in order of "0b00000101, 0b01110001, 0b01000111, and 0b01000010" which I each read as uint32 bytes and then bit-shift the 2nd byte left by 8 bits, the 3rd byte left by 16 bits, and the 4th byte left by 24 bits. Then I can add them all together (making 0b01000010010001110111000100000101) and convert the composite uint32 to a float. The real trick is the implementation - figuring out the code tools to get that job done.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not to worry, this is not too difficult.

I've reworked your pseudo-code so it compiles as a C snippet. I believe the main part of your question is about how to pull in and assemble a multibyte value. In the code blocks below, this is the `decode` function.

When dealing with a binary packet like you have, it is much better to use `unsigned char` instead of merely `char`. This makes the shifting easier/more correct.

You said that the packet is *newline* terminated, but this doesn't show up in the diagram.  And, because we're dealing with *binary* data [as you confirmed in your top comments], any valid byte in the data portion of the packet could be 0x0A (i.e. newline), so we *can't* just read char-by-char until we see newline.

*If* there is, indeed, a newline at the end, we may need to read 25 bytes and just check the last char.

I don't do windows :-), so I don't know the specifics of accessing the COM port, but I've coded up functions that you can fill in.

---

Anyway, the code is below [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char Text[100];
} TextBox_t;

FILE *stream;

TextBox_t gas1textBox;
TextBox_t gas2textBox;
TextBox_t temptextBox;
TextBox_t ErrortextBox;

// serial_data_is_available -- check for data ready
int
serial_data_is_available(void)
{

    return 1;
}

// serial_get -- get single byte from device
unsigned char
serial_get(void)
{

    return rand();
}

// serial_buf -- assemble packet buffer
int
serial_buf(unsigned char *buf,int buflen)
{
    int idx;

    for (idx = 0;  idx < buflen;  ++idx)
        buf[idx] = serial_get();

    return idx;
}

// decode -- get a binary value
uint32_t
decode(unsigned char *buf,int beg,int end)
{
    uint32_t acc = 0;

    for (int idx = end;  idx >= beg;  --idx) {
        acc <<= 8;
        acc |= buf[idx];
    }

    return acc;
}

// floatget -- get a float value
float
floatget(unsigned char *buf,int beg,int end)
{
    union {
        float fval;
        uint32_t val;
    } join;

    join.val = decode(buf,beg,end);

    return join.fval;
}

// process_packet -- process a single packet
void
process_packet(void)
{
    // for raw binary data, unsigned is better
    unsigned char buf[24];

    // read serial packet into char array
    serial_buf(buf,sizeof(buf));

    // "{" part of packet
    char start = buf[0];

    // "}" part of bracket
    char end = buf[23];

    //if packet is as expected…
    if ((start == '{') && (end == '}')){
        // gas measurement 1 data from packet
        float Gas1Float = floatget(buf,6,9);

        // gas measurement 2 data from packet
        float Gas2Float = floatget(buf,10,13);

        // temp measurement from packet
        float tempFloat = floatget(buf,14,17);

        sprintf(gas1textBox.Text,"%f",Gas1Float);
        sprintf(gas2textBox.Text,"%f",Gas2Float);
        sprintf(temptextBox.Text,"%f",tempFloat);
    }
    else {
        strcpy(ErrortextBox.Text,"Packet error"); //unexpected packet error
    }
}

void
loop(void)
{

    while (1) {
        if (serial_data_is_available())
            process_packet();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `val = decode(buf,beg,end);` is missing the cast. As coded it interprets the return value as integer, and promoted it to float. In fact, the bit pattern of the return value already represents the float, and shall be reinterpreted as such: `val = (float) decode(buf,beg,end);`

Comment: @user58697 Good catch, thanks. But, I think the conversion needs a bit more trickery (ala the `union`). So, I've cleaned up and combined both code examples into one